# Hazelcast 3.8 module and configuration possibility for wildfly 10.1?

Tags: hazelcast, jca, jcache

I like to prototype a JEE environment with Wildfly 10.1 and Hazelcast 3.8. Until now I only have experience with ancient JBoss 4.2.3.GA.

I already found existing **resource adapter** implementation based on older hazelcast 3.6 under https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-ra. Unfortunately I couldn't deploy it **as-is** on Wildfly 10.1 since IronJacamar complained about missing equals/hashCode methods (*which isn't true since they are explictly overwritten in the source code. deploying a self-built snapshot of git master had the same issue*).

I ended up with migrating the ra.xml configuration code to proper javax.resource.spi annotations (@Connector, @ConfigProperty, @ConnectionDefinition) and adding javax.resource.Referenceable interface implementation (don't know whether this is necessary). The step to hazelcast 3.8 was much easier - just adding missing interface methods to HazelcastConnectionImpl.

I still struggle with deployment/configuration, so here are my questions:

1. **How should the deployment structure for an JCA adapter look like?** I tested the following approaches:

   - **All-in-one:** RAR file containing all of `cache-api-1.0.0.jar`, `hazelcast-3.8.jar`, `hazelcast-client-3.8.jar`, `my-hazelcast-ra-impl.jar` and deployment descriptors.
   - **By-Library:** Added new modules `javax.cache.api` (`cache-api-1.0.0.jar`) and `com.hazelcast.hazelcast` (`hazelcast-3.8.jar`, `hazelcast-client-3.8.jar`) to `${WILDFLY_HOME}/modules/` and declared appropriate module dependencies in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. RAR file contains `my-hazelcast-ra-impl.jar`, `hazelcast.xml` and deployment descriptors.
   - **By-Adapter:** Added a new module `my.hazelcast.ra` (`cache-api-1.0.0.jar`, `my-hazelcast-ra-impl.jar`) to `${WILDFLY_HOME}/modules/` and declared appropriate module dependency in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. RAR file contains `hazelcast-3.8.jar`, `hazelcast-client-3.8.jar`, `hazelcast.xml` and deployment descriptors.
2. **Where is the proper place to deploy a hazelcast.xml configuration file into Wildfly 10.1?** It seems that I **need to pack it next to ResourceAdapterImpl class** (`my-hazelcast-ra-impl.jar`) so that the **class loader finds it** and prefers it over hazelcast-default.xml. It contains only global configuration options like group/network. No cache definitions since caches should be configured/created on-demand via CDI.

   - Is there something like a `conf` folder where I can deploy `hazelcast.xml` file separate from binary RAR contents? It would be nice if it could be hot-deployed (for prototyping) but that is not mandatory.
   - Should it be placed somehow inside subsystem configurations within standalone.xml? I found similar cache-container configurations for infinispan subsystem but don't know how to adapt this to hazelcast (since it's not an own subsystem).
3. In Wildfly Management webinterface I can find the deployed RAR under Depoyments and in the JNDI view, but it is not listed under Configuration -> Subsystems -> Resource Adapters. I can create a new entry there but don't find any advantage. **What is the meaning of this configuration option?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: For development deployment, I would simply embed hazelcast into the web application WAR / EAR. For production deployment, I would recommend to setup a separate Hazelcast cluster. The web application then connects as client to hazelcast. I don't know much what JCA is so I can't help you much on that point sadly.

Comment: I am not a Wildfly/JCA configuration expert, so cannot answer your Wildfly configuration questions. I created an issue about not being able to deploy the currently released hazelcast-ra on Wildfly at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-ra/issues/7 . Any additional information you may provide is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @VassilisBekiaris I'm actually off for Easter holiday but I may provide my modifications on a github branch when back to work next week. For now I can give you some hints: there is one configuration property of a primitive type (boolean?), which has to be replaced by its wrapper type (solves 3rd warning message). Look into ra.xml to find the properties. The other properties must annotated with @@ConfigProperty. Annotate ResourceAdapterImpl with @@Connector. Annotate ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl with @@ConnectionDefinition. Also you must create a jboss-deployment-structure.xml.

Comment: Example migration steps are now available in [my wildfly10 branch](https://github.com/rkowalke/hazelcast-ra/tree/wildfly10). For further discussions about "migration" please use [issue tracking](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-ra/issues/7).